# Nginx rewrite for folder

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm am having a problem with my rewrite rule in Nginx

Here is what I have:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)$ /index.php?p=$1;
}
```

I have a folder named `example` in my HTML folder for Nginx. I want to take my GET variables and put them behind the URL like folders.

Basically I need

`www.example.com/example/index.php?p=something&var=something2`

to look like

`www.example.com/something/something2`

Any help would be great. I'm switching from Apache to Nginx and it's a bit confusing.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was in a rush.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)$ /example/index.php?p=$1&var=$2;
```